# Moving IK target with Unity's New Input System

Tags: unity, c#, input, inverse-kinematics

I'm currently converting our 2D game from the old input system to the new input system in the hopes of making it available to more people in the future. Currently I am using the mouse position to aim a flashlight by moving the IK target of that arm to the mouse position by getting the vector of the mouse cursor and converting it using screentoworldpoint. My question is, how can I implement a similar function using the new input system with a joystick? Currently I am getting a vector2 from the joystick which ranges from (-1,-1) to (1,1) depending on the position and angle of the joystick. I would like to have the same code for both inputs so I don't have to use an if else statement and determine what input is being used but if that is unavoidable I understand. I would just like to know the best way to go about aiming an IK target using a joystick with the new input system.

Comment: I don't think you can use 100% the same code path for both cases. The input ranges and meanings are different. A mouse cursor points at a specific position in the world, while an analog stick gives a relative direction.

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. I know I can just skip the IK and go to the shoulder bone and do a rotation from there based on the angle which might allow me to use the same code for both but when I tried that it was really laggy compared to using the mouse cursor to move the IK targets position.